# Selenium w/Python3 - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name' can you help me please

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, selenium-rc

```
        capturarId = driver.find_element(By.tag_name,"iframe").send_keys('id')
        iframe = driver.find_element(by.xpath,"//iframe[@id='"+capturarId+"']")
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe[0])
```

code and next error type object 'By' has no attribute 'tag_name' please can you help me

Comment: TAG_NAME improper capitalization. Same with XPATH.

Comment: I already did it, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

You have given as iframe[0], iframe is Webelement not array hence you have to write in below way.

```
capturarId = driver.find_element(By.tag_name,"iframe").send_keys('id')
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='"+capturarId+"']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: no nothing error, name 'by' is not defined

Comment: I have updated my answer, changed by to By

Comment: no nothing :((((((